# Installing JetBrains Toolbox on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, 17.10, ubuntu-gnome

I'm trying to install JetBrains Toolbox 1.6.2914 on Ubuntu 17.10

I extracted the `tar.gz` archive into `/opt` directory and I can correctly launch the application using terminal (or double clicking on the executable icon).

But I cannot find it in Gnome application menu. And the application is not even launched a system startup.

How can I properly install Toolbox on my machine?

Answer (score 10):

If you launch the Toolbox application once you can click the icon in the top bar and go to settings and you'll see a check box to set it to launch at startup. To get the application to show up in the application menu, you need to have a `.desktop` file for it (mine is in `~./local/share/applications`), I'm not entirely sure how mine arrived there, but I've put it below. You'll want to replace `<username>` with your actual username, and you may want to comment out the `Icon` line because you may not have that file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=JetBrains Toolbox
Exec=/home/<username>/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/bin/jetbrains-toolbox %u
Icon=/home/<username>/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/toolbox.svg
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-toolbox
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/jetbrains;
```

Comment: With Toolbok 1.8.3678 this seems not necessary and it is automatically created on first start.

Answer (score 3):

With Toolbox 1.8.3678+, it is automatically created on the first start. So you just need to put it somewhere and open it.

> Based on the comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: It would be nice if they wrote *something* to stdout.